# Layout process slows down after updating Chrome to version 60

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, typescript

After Chrome update to version 60, my application (Typescript + React) works very slowly. Using *Performance* tab in Chrome Dev Tools, I found out that the browser takes sick time rendering elements (the *Layout* process).

[Summary time graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV5cM.png)

Has anyone encountered such problem? What could possibly cause this? The code is the same for sure, I have checked once more on two different versions of Chrome. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: What versions of TypeScript and React?

Comment: TypeScript 2.4.1.0, React 15.0

Comment: Try upgrading to React 15.6.1, we got very significant performance boosts.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Okay, seems like the problem lies in the site layout which was built using Grid. For some reason, after Chrome update, this layout became very slow in my app - I have tried to build the layout using grid, flexbox and floats, the first two are horribly slow and floats work just fine.

Comment: What bothers me though is, flexbox and grid have been out there for a while now so I bet many websites use it, and, yet, I haven't seen a single post about performance issues after Chrome 60 update so it still looks like a deeper problem in my app...

Comment: I have the same problem =(.

Answer (score 0):

After version 60, when I opened a new browser window (Ctrl-N or Ctrl-Shift-N) I had everything inside Chrome totally SLOW, even typing.
I solved it disabling option "Use hardware acceleration when available" in Chrome settings.
Cheers
PS: I am using Linux Mint 18 sarah